# How many segments go through 2 parallel lines' points?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics

$2$ parallel lines $a$ and $b$ have points $A_1,A_2,...,A_n\in a$ and $B_1,B_2,...,B_m\in b$ on them. How many intersection points will there be if we will draw segments $A_iB_j$ ($1\leqslant i\leqslant n,1\leqslant j\leqslant m$), with the contition that no $3$ of these segments can intersect in $1$ point?

Comment: it is missing since your condition on three segment intersection depends on the repartition of points.

Comment: The question is inconsistent when it says that no $3$ of these segments can intersect in $1$ point.  Certainly $A_1B_1, A_1B_2,$ and $A_1B_3$ intersect in the point $A_1$.  I suspect they do not intend you to count the intersections at the A and B points, just the intersections between the lines, but it is not written that way.

Comment: A math question is off topic on a math forum, ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Try it with two points on each line.  How many ways of drawing the segments lead to an intersection?  Now how many ways to select a pair of points from each line?

Comment: Okay, with 2 points on each line we have 5 intersections, correct? How many ways of drawing the segments lead to an intersection? << you lost me there.

Comment: Clearly you will have intersections at all the points on each line.  We are most interested in intersections between the lines.  If you have two points on each line you can draw four segments.  How many intersections are there between the lines?

Comment: Sorry, I think I answered the question, but maybe you mean something else, if we have 2 points on each line, there's 1 between the lines intersection and 4 on-line intersections, that make a total of 5.

Comment: Yes, I see where $5$ comes from.  Yes, there is $1$ between the lines.  You should be able to convince yourself that there will be one intersection between the lines for each set of two A points and two B points.  Then you just need to find the number of these sets.

Comment: The answer in the book is $C_m^2\times C_n^2$, but the book is known to have wrong answers.

Comment: I am suggesting how to get there. That is correct.

Comment: I am trying to convince myself that if I have 3 points on each line, I will get 9, but I can't even draw such an example.

Comment: Oh, I see, this dumb book doesn't consider 2 or more segments coming out of one on-line point to be an intersection.

Comment: so, basically we choose 2 points from the first line and then another 2 points from the second one and draw an "X"? This is the answer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  For each pair of pairs you get one intersection point.

Comment: Okay, this is easy, but the problem statement is confusing. Thanks.